# Is it possible to create a build for unreleased versions of iOS using a non-beta Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, release

I'm wanting to create a release build to run on iOS10.3, which is presently in beta. I know that I have to use Xcode 8.3 (beta) in order to run in *debug* on iOS10.3 devices.

Can I use Xcode 8.2 to create this *release* build so the resulting IPA will still successfully run on iOS10.3? I don't really want to use a beta version of Xcode to create a production build.

Comment: You cannot target 10.3 with Xcode 8.2 but you can target 10.2 (or earlier) and expect it to run on 10.3 when it is released. If your app is targeting 10.3 specifically then you will need to wait until Apple gives the OK to submit 10.3 apps

Comment: @Paulw11 by that you mean if I used part of the 10.3 API, ie. set base SDK?

Comment: He means if you link against 10.3.

Comment: OK appreciate your advice both

Comment: If your app *requires* 10.3; ie it uses some feature such that it can't run on earlier version then you have to wait, otherwise target 10.0 (or 9.x or whatever is the earliest your code requires) and submit with xcode 8.2. You can use the beta Xcode and beta iOS to *test* to see if there will be any issues when 10.3 is released end either report a bug to Apple or modify your code